# Change background color slider-nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the link

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15260/)

I want the side bar color to red and hover color #C9302C.

Here i tried CSS, but on scrolling the page , the side bar coming to down..

Why this . Any idea??

```
<style>
     .sidebar-nav {
width: 250px; /*Changed from max-width: 200px to better fit smaller menu items, but this is up to your preference*/
z-index: 10000;
position: fixed;
min-height: 100%; /*Makes it fit 100% of your pages content*/
background: #EE1B24;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19062/

Comment: It is unclear what is your question. What is your expected output?

Comment: What i do if not unclear my question..people are answering , there are some people who downvote if they cant answer :lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  .navbar-default {
    background:red;
    }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    background:#C9302C;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19061/

Comment: Be more specific in your request then please..  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19066/  `.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {  background:red; }`

Comment: Yes...am getting this style when applying your answer, whats wrong

Comment: I've answered your question based on, what I interpreted as, what you asked for. If you're requiring something completely different, please be more specific in your initial request.

Comment: I indicated the change I made in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
  .navbar {
    background: red;
  }

  .sidebar-nav .navbar li:hover {
    background: #C9302C;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css to override the default bootstrap css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover a{

  color:#C9302C;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{

  color:#FF0000;

}
```